# Why doesn't HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode throw an exception when it doesn't find a padding character?

Tags: c#, httpserverutility

So, let's throw a nonsense string at [`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true), and ensure that it ends in the digit 0-9:

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode("fu&+bar0");
```

and it blows up with a `FormatException`.

Now let's try the same *without* the number at the end:

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode("fu&+bar");
```

No exception occurs and the method returns null.

I understand that the character at the end is meant to represent the number of padding characters that would occur when the string is base64 encoded, and that by the algorithm, this is only permitted to be a digit character between 0-9, as we can see in this decompiled code:

```
int num = (int) input[length - 1] - 48;
if (num < 0 || num > 10)
{
    return (byte[]) null;
}
```

So my question is: why does this method return null when handed a particular type of corrupted token, but throw an exception when a different type of corruption is encountered? Is there a rationale behind this decision, or is it just a case of sloppy implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the source code for [`HttpServerutility.UrlTokenDecode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,87ca8896ddb0e61b) yourself.

But essentially when there is a number at the end of the input, it passes the first stage of evaluation and gets passed into the Base64 decoding routines. Inside those routines is where the `FormatException` is raised due to the nonsense input.